# $-u''+u=\delta_y$ where $u(0)=u(1)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta, weak-derivatives

Let $0<y<1$ be arbitrary. What is the weak solution of the differential equation

$-u''+u=\delta_y$ where $u(0)=u(1)=0$

then? The weak form of the equation above is given by

$\int_0^1{u'(t)v'(t)+u(t)v(t)dt}=v(y)$ for all $v\in H_0^1((0, 1))$.

Comment: Suggestion: solve it on $(0,y)$ and $(y,1)$ separately (each solution will involve one free parameter). Choose parameters so that the solution is continuous at $y$ but its first derivative changes by $-1$. This will introduce $-\delta_y$ in $u''$.

Comment: As Normal Human explained you can easily solve the equation in a pedestrian way. What is the purpose of looking at the weak solution? To give a proper meaning to the delta distribution?