# boundary value problem $-u''+u=\delta_y$ where $u'(0)=u'(1)=0$

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

> Consider the boundary value problem (BVP) $$-u''+u=\delta_y\;\text{on}\; I=(0,1)$$ $$u'(0)=u'(1)=0,$$where $y\in I$, $\delta_y:H^1(I)\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $\delta_y(v)=v(y)$. For all $y\in I$ find a weak solution $u\in H^1(I)$ of the BVP.

This means, I have to consider $$\int_0^1{u'(t)v'(t)+u(t)v(t)dt}=v(y)$$ for all $v\in H^1((0, 1))$ and maybe it's useful to consider $(0,y)$ and $(y,1)$ and $\int_0^y{u'(t)v'(t)+u(t)v(t)dt}=v(y)$ and $\int_y^1{u'(t)v'(t)+u(t)v(t)dt}=v(y)$, but I'm not sure. How do I find $u$?

Comment: Are you required to write down the weak form and then work directly from there? There are other approaches, for instance you can write down the general solution to the ODE (e.g. using Laplace transforms) and then choose constants to satisfy the boundary conditions.

Comment: yes, for me it's only allowed to write down the weak form and work directly from here. We had no other approaches in lecture.

Comment: You're sure you cannot, say, perform scratch work on the ODE to get a guess and then plug it into the weak form to check it? It is not so simple to directly attack the weak form, since all you can really do is choose test functions to get a bunch of separate equations. By contrast the ODE itself is not that difficult to solve.

Comment: okay. But I don't know how the solve the ODE, I belief I have no theory for that, if I don't oversee something.

Comment: There are various ways to see it, depending on what you've already proven. At the end of the day, I can think of two approaches. One is to say that $-u''+u=\delta_y$ means that $-u''+u=0$ for $t \neq y$, $u$ is continuous at $y$, and $u'$ has a jump of size $-1$ at $y$. (This involves some slightly technical work with distribution theory.) The other is to say that the Laplace transform of $\delta_y$ is $e^{-ys}$ (which follows immediately from the definition), then use the properties of the Laplace transform.

Comment: Going the latter way, the problem reduces to finding the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{su(0)-e^{-ys}}{s^2-1}$ and then choosing $u(0)$ such that $u'(1)=0$.

Comment: It seems that the question has much in common with http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1562904/uu-delta-y-where-u0-u1-0

Comment: oh, interesting. I didn't notice that there already is a similar question on math-stackexchange, sorry! @Ian thanks a lot for your help! Why should be $-u''+u=0$ for $t\neq y$? $\delta_y$ is not the function which sends t to zero if $y\neq t$ and which sends t to 1 otherwise. Or is $-u''+u=0$ for $t\neq y$ a "trick" to find out what the solution is?

Comment: @analysis $\delta_y$ does not map $y$ to $1$, you're right, but the actual contribution of $\delta_y$ to the solution I stated is in furnishing the jump in $u'$ at $y$. Elsewhere it does nothing, so everywhere else you indeed have $-u''+u=0$.

Comment: ah ok! thanks for your explanation. i will try to follow your approach with the Laplace transform! Thank you. If you want you could write in an answer your hints, i think they will be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

The thing to notice is that $-u''+u=0$ for $x < y$ and for $x > y$. So you have to piece together eigenfunctions. On the left, you want $u'(0)=0$ and on the right you want $u'(1)=0$. Then solutions of these problems are
$$
                  u(x)=A\cosh(x),\;\;\;\;\;\;\; 0 \le x < y  \\
                  u(x)=B\cosh(x-1), \;\;\;\; y < x \le 1.
$$
Then you have to piece these together at $y$ in such a way that the function is continuous in $x$ at $x=y$, and the derivative has a jump discontinuity of $-1$ at $x=y$. That way $-u''$ gives you a delta function. There are two conditions
$$
                A\cosh(y)-B\cosh(y-1) = 0 \\
                B\sinh(y-1)-A\sinh(y) = -1.
$$
That's a simple 2x2 system for $A$, $B$, and the determinant of the coefficient matrix is a Wronskian, which does not vanish. So everything is good. I'll let you determine the values of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Here the *derivative* vanishes rather than the function value so you actually want solutions in the form of $\cosh$, not $\sinh$.

Comment: @Ian : I changed it.

Comment: A good approach now, +1. I'll leave my answer since our methods complement one another.

Answer (score 1):

You can work with the ODE directly to get a "formal" solution and then check that it satisfies the weak form of the equation. One way to do this is to use the Laplace transform; the definition of the Dirac delta and of the Laplace transform tells you that the Laplace transform of $\delta_y$ is $e^{-ys}$. The Laplace transform of the left side is $-s^2U+su(0)+u'(0)+U=(-s^2+1)U+su(0)$. So you have

$$U=\frac{su(0)-e^{-ys}}{s^2-1}.$$

You can use partial fraction decomposition and the inverse Laplace transform to solve this for $u$, keeping $u(0)$ as a free parameter. We already used $u'(0)=0$, so you then need to choose $u(0)$ to make $u'(1)=0$. You should then *check* that the solution satisfies the weak equation (since the strong equation does not make pointwise sense at $y$).